# Can anyone tell me what other computers used this floating-point format?

Tags: computer-architecture, computers, floating-point

I have discovered that the DEC PDP-10 used a floating-point format that differed from IEEE-754 in an interesting way.

[IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is like [sign-magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) representation.  The only difference between a positive value and its negative is the value of the MSB of the word.  Assuming no `NaN`s, if you use an integer subtractor to compare two IEEE floats, the compare operation yields the correct result in 3 out of 4 cases.  The case where the integer compare result is wrong is when both values are negative.

The DEC PDP-10 had the same mantissa with *"hidden 1 bit"*, offset binary exponent to the left of the mantissa, but when the numbers were negative, the PDP-10 represented that value as the **2's complement** of the positive value.  So there was no "-0" representation (just one 0) and the integer compare operation worked in any case.

This is clever.  I wonder what other early computers may have used this and **why** didn't this catch on with IEEE?

If you combine this clever formatting with floats with denormals, you can have a floating-point representation that is monotonic mapping that is a piecewise-linear approximation to the `arcsinh()` function when mapping the floating-point value to an integer having the same bit pattern in the word.  Seems like a clever idea missed by whatever IEEE committee that first came up with 754.

I suppose they wanted "-0" so that if an operation like `1/x` was done, they would know whether to use `+INF` or `-INF`, but if you leave that "feature" out and leave out `NaN`s, this format can assign **every** bit pattern to a numerical value that is a strictly-increasing mapping and that seems like a valuable feature.  Every bit pattern is a number and a unique number.  No `NaN`s or `INF`s or other goofy bit patterns to cause an exception.

Comment: I recommend reading Goldberg's paper "what every computer scientist should know about floating point" where some difficulties get obvious, which seem to have made the current one more favourable within certain architectures, that then spread and everyone copied them. If you want to see another neat fp trick you might want to look into the vax (i think) format where the first 32 bits of a 64 bit double are a valid 32 bit float

Comment: thank you.  [easy to find.](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~robert/teaching/master/material/p5-goldberg.pdf)

Comment: http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: been there @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams .

Comment: [found this interesting.](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cp0201.htm)

Comment: [nerd-sniping](https://xkcd.com/356/) rbj here: Have you heard about [unum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)), a pretty freshly invented computational number format, which [might be cooler than IEEE754](http://www.johngustafson.net/presentations/Right-SizingPrecision1.pdf) and relatives due to having accurateness and magnitude info "tagged" onto the number?

Comment: looks like it has a lotta baggage.